# Странности префиксного декремента и условия в программе на C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

При нажатии на кнопку, чуть ниже её добавляется ещё одна кнопка и это должно быть возможным всего 8 раз

```
Button[] bt = new Button[8];
    private int i { get; set; } = 1;
    private void home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bt[0] = addButton1;
    }
    public void addButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (i <= 8)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            bt[i] = new Button();

            bt[i].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            bt[i].FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            bt[i].FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
            bt[i].FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent;
            bt[i].FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            bt[i].ForeColor = Color.White;
            bt[i].Image = Properties.Resources.add;
            bt[i].Location = new Point(543, 132);
            bt[i].Name = "addButton" + i.ToString();
            bt[i].Size = new Size(37, 28);
            bt[i].UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            bt[i].Location = new Point(b.Location.X, b.Location.Y + 32);

            Controls.Add(bt[i]);

            bt[i].Click += new EventHandler(addButton1_Click);

            bt[i - 1].Image = Properties.Resources.remove;
            i++;
        }
    }
```

**Во-первых**, я не совсем понимаю почему если стоит условие if(i<=8) я всё равно могу нажать на последнюю (восьмую) кнопку и даже получить после этого ошибку.
**Во-вторых**, у меня была некая проблема, а точнее не добавлялись кнопки. Я долго не мог понять в чём проблема, а потом методом тыка починил, заменив:

```
bt[--i].Image = Properties.Resources.remove;
```

на:

```
bt[i - 1].Image = Properties.Resources.remove;
```

И всё начало работать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не знаю как с# , но в java индексация массива начинается с `0`.
и массив размерностью `[8]` имеет индексы от `0` до `7` (длинна массива - 1)

```
if (i <= 8)
```

и здесь при проверке i на равенство 8ми получим выход за пределы массива т.к. последний элемент у нас под индексом 7.

попробуйте условие проверки i до 8   `if (i < 8)`

Comment: О боже, я такой глупец. Больше не буду кодить пьяным xddd. Но только почему когда я использовал Префиксный Декремент у меня не уменьшалось значение переменой i? Замена на "i - 1" всё исправила, но разве это не одно и тоже?

Comment: @АлексейКарпунов Нет, это не одно и то же. `--i` меняет значение переменной `i`, а `i - 1` - не меняет.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (i < 8)
    {
      ...
      bt[i].Image = Properties.Resources.remove;
    }
```

Comment: Нет, мне нужно именно чтобы предыдущая кнопка меняла картинку на другую. Ваш код меняет текущую картинку, что и так уже делается чуть выше